# NextJS-Auth0: How can I assign a role on signup with Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0

Using the library nextjs-auth0 (https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) I've been trying to make use of the `handleAuth` hook to grab a query arg to specify which role should be assigned to the user on signup.

An example of what I'm *trying* to do:

```js
//pages/api/auth/[...auth0].js

const getLoginState = (req, loginOptions) => {
    const  { role } = req.query;
    return { role: role };
  };

export default handleAuth({
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
          await handleLogin(req, res, { getLoginState } );
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
        }
      }
});
```

The documentation for `handleAuth` makes it seem like it's possible to do this ( https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/handlers_login.html#getloginstate )

```js
// from the documentation
const getLoginState = (req, loginOptions) => {
  return { basket_id: getBasketId(req) };
};
```

From that doc - it looks like `basket_id` is the custom property to be saved against the user "before they visit the Identity Provider to login".
This sounds, to me, that `basked_id` will be saved somewhere against the users metadata once they've logged in. Is the documentation misleading, or am I misunderstanding?

How can I set the role during  (or even slightly after) signup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted with the following Auth0 "rule":

```js
function (user, context, callback) {

    const count = context.stats && context.stats.loginsCount ? context.stats.loginsCount : 0;
    if (count > 1) {
        return callback(null, user, context);
    }

    const ManagementClient = require('auth0@2.27.0').ManagementClient;
    const management = new ManagementClient({
      token: auth0.accessToken,
      domain: auth0.domain
    });
    let roles = [context.request.query.role];
    const params =  { id : user.user_id};
    const data = { "roles" : roles};

    management.users.assignRoles(params, data, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error.
        console.log(err);
     }
    callback(null, user, context);
    });
    
}
```

Notice that the role is being read in from `context.request.query.role`. This pulls the query param `role` key off the login URL which more-or-less works how I wanted it to.

Then forward the role along from the auth in the backend:

```js
const getLoginState = (req, loginOptions) => {
    const  { role } = req.query;
    loginOptions.authorizationParams.role = role;
    return { role: role };
  };

export default handleAuth({
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
          await handleLogin(req, res, { getLoginState });
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
        }
      }
});
```

Notice the     `loginOptions.authorizationParams.role = role;`

So the login link can be set to: `/api/auth/login?role=somerole` and the rule will pick up the role and set it in the metadata part of the users info.

**However: I wasn't able to get this to actually properly set the role on the user** but it's enough for me, as it appears in the session.